# What is the time resolution for the callback on YouTube HTML5 API?

Tags: ios, youtube-api

We have built an application using the old YouTube flash API which polls the player for it's current time using: player.getCurrentTime(). We currently poll the player at 40ms intervals in order to update screen components at 25 fps. This API isn't supported on iOS so we tested the HTML5 API. It seems that we can not poll the player as frequently as 40ms using the HTML5 API. It appears to max out at about 100ms polling intervals forcing our screen updates to be very jerky. Is this a known limitation of the HTML5 API or is there a way to poll the player at finer intervals?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What function are you using for your polling? If you're using setInterval or setTimeout, you could see if you get less jerky performance with requestAnimationFrame.

Regardless, though, it may not matter; the iframe API (which is the only one that offers HTML5 playback) doesn't have that granular of access to the player's current time. In fact, the player inside the iframe only does a postMessage to update the time accessible via getCurrentTime about 5-6 times a second, so polling any more frequently than that is just wasting CPU cycles. (I'm not sure why they do it this way, as HTML5 video by default updates its current time about 50 times a second).

Comment: Thanks for the info. I'm still trying to gather more information on it but for now we are interpolating any animation we do between the polling intervals.